# Drive File Stream altering my file names to add (1) at the end of their names

Tags: winforms, google-drive-shared-drive

I am writing a program using WinForms in C# which monitors my drive file stream files, and copies the files to a local directory, where the files can then be run locally off of the computer.

My issue I am having is that when I alter or replace the files in the drive file stream either through the desktop app or the browser, it will rename some files to add an additional (1) at the end of the name. This then messes with the files when I need to run them from the local directory on my computer, as it cannot locate these specific files anymore.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks.